# Images not saved when saving a web page !

Tags: php, css, image, zend-framework, download

I am building a web site using php. I'm using Zend framework on an Apache server. My `www` folder structure is the following:

```
+www  
|  
|_+css  
| |  
| |_images  
|  
|_js  
|  
|_images
```

now the problem is whenever I save a page the images inside the 2 image folders(1 inside www and the other inside css) aren't saved.

when I explore the saved page using firebug I find the css of a certain div referring to an image inside a folder named images (which isn't created).

[link to image](http://img830.imageshack.us/i/ixscbkhl.jpg/)

...so can anyone tell me what's wrong ? 

coz now I have to manually copy the 2 images folders with the saved file every time.

Comment: "Save" using what program or script or function?

Comment: Save using File->save page as... this on both Chrome and Firefox !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean 'save the page with firefox's save the page option': This option is broken, and it doesn't save everything. There is a plugin for firefox to fix this:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/save-complete-4723/

Comment: Thanks. This was the problem indeed. Never imagined that it would be a browser problem. By the way the same problem happens on Chrome ! I used the plugin you provided and it solved the problem on firefox. any idea how to solve it on chrome ?!

Answer (score 0):

Generally browsers will only Save any `<img>` Images, and won't spend the time grabbing every image mentioned in the CSS.

Comment: well the images that aren't being saved are indeed mentioned in the CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

When you added the jQueryUI stylesheet, did you also copy the images that came with it?

Unfortunately, I'm not 100% what you mean by "whenever I save a page".

Comment: yes I added the images that come with jQueryUI to my project. As I stated before when I run my project everything works fine. The images are there but when I choose File->save Page as... some of the images aren't saved with the web page.